# Mapping string with key-value pair to object

Tags: javascript

Given the following string with key-value pairs, how would you write a generic function to map it to an object?

At the moment, I am just splitting by `:` and `;` to get the relevant data, but it doesn't seem like a clean approach.

This my code at the moment:

```
var pd = `id:S76519;sku:S76519;name:StarGazer 3000;model:ICC74`;
var tempPd = pd.split(';');
for (i = 1; i < tempPd.length; i++) {
    var b = tempPd[i].split(':');
    console.log(b[1]);
}
```

Comment: Well what you're doing is pretty much the only thing you can do. If you've got a string and you want to extract information according to a syntax you expect to find, then you *parse* the string and build a data structure.

Comment: if you know that there are no ; and : in the keys and values then why not?

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using currently? It's hard to know if there's a more clean approach without seeing what you've already got.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior this my approach at the moment, as the first two values are identical, i start my increment at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using reduce:

```js
function objectify(str) {

 return str.split(";").reduce(function (obj, item) {
  var a = item.split(":");
  obj[a[0]] = a[1];
  return obj;
 }, {});

}

var strObj = "id:S76519;sku:S76519;name:StarGazer 3000;model:ICC74";
console.log(objectify(strObj));
```

or:

```js
function objectify(str){

return str.split(";").reduce((obj,item)=>{  
   var a = item.split(":");
   obj[a[0]]=a[1];
   return obj;  
},{});

}
 
var strObj = "id:S76519;sku:S76519;name:StarGazer 3000;model:ICC74";
console.log(objectify(strObj));
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!